# Windows Azure learning resources for individual developers.

Tags: azure

I'm a single developer working on an idea I'd like to deploy to windows azure, however my main issue is I couldn't find any good learning resources for individual developers working alone. Does anyone have any recommendations? I've got the azure platform training kit, but from what I can tell, it's intended more for teams of developers learning at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the prior owner, I can tell you that the platform training kit was targeting to anyone looking to learn about the platform - not just teams.  If I was trying to get up to speed, I would sit down and start on the hands on labs, but I am biased towards the kit.

Cory keeps an updated list of ['Essential Windows Azure Resources'](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2010/12/30/Essential-Resources-for-Getting-Started-with-Windows-Azure.aspx) I would take a look at as well, there are some good items in it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the book "Azure in Action"

Comment: Book looks interesting, ordered it from amazon.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Cloud cover show at channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover) very helpful in my learning. Try it